# Redux-thunk with promise does not work

Tags: javascript, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I am trying to chain dispatches with redux-thunk. I have 2 action creator as below:

**getResourceLinks**:

```
export const getResourceLinks = () => {
  return dispatch => {
    let req = {
      url: getRootUrl(),
      header: {
        Accept: 'application/json'
      }
    };
    return request(req).then(res => {
      dispatch({
        type: ActionTypes.RESOURCE.LOAD_URL_SUCCESS,
        payload: res.body
      });
    }).catch(err => {
      dispatch({
        type: ActionTypes.RESOURCE.LOAD_URL_ERROR,
        payload: err
      });
    });
  }
};
```

and **loadAppliances**:

```
export const loadAppliances = () => {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    return dispatch(getResourceLinks()).then(res => {
      const {resources} = getState();
      let req = {
        url: getResourceLink(Resources.Appliances, res.body),
        header: {
          Accept: 'application/json'
        }
      };
      request(req).then(res1 => {
        dispatch({
          type: ActionTypes.APPLIANCE.LOAD_SUCCESS,
          payload: res1.body
        });
      }).catch(err => {
        dispatch({
          type: ActionTypes.APPLIANCE.LOAD_ERROR,
          payload: err
        });
      });
    });
  };
};
```

I am facing with an error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined` at line 3 in **loadAppliances** action. Promise was returned correctly, wasn't it? Am I doing wrong something? I've seen carefully examples of thunk-redux but I don't still find out what was wrong.

**Update**. Here is request:

```
import superagent from 'superagent';
import superagentPromisePlugin from 'superagent-promise-plugin';
import {RequestMethods} from '../constant';

const request = ({url, method = RequestMethods.GET, param, body, header}) => {
  let methodStr;
  switch (method) {
    case RequestMethods.POST:
      methodStr = 'POST';
      break;
    case RequestMethods.PUT:
      methodStr = 'PUT';
      break;
    case RequestMethods.DELETE:
      methodStr = 'DELETE';
      break;
    default:
      methodStr = 'GET';
      break;
  }
  let req = superagent(methodStr, url).use(superagentPromisePlugin);
  //set header
  if (header) {
    req.set(header)
  }
  //set param
  if (param) {
    req.query(param)
  }
  //set body
  if (body) {
    req.send(body)
  }
  return req;
};

export default request;
```

Comment: can you provide request function

Comment: @Utro I've updated my question with request function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that `dispatch` does not return your promise. It actually returns the dispatched action itself. ([reference](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/master/src/createStore.js#L180)).

```
return dispatch(getResourceLinks()).then(res => {
                                   ^--- this is the problem
```

The way I would approach this is to dispatch an action after your first successful call and store any pertinent information in the state, then dispatch the next call and store its response.

## Example

```
const getResourceLinks = () => {
  return request({
    url: getRootUrl(),
    header: {
      Accept: 'application/json'
    }
  });
};

const getAppliances = (appliances) => {
  return request({
    url: getResourceLink(Resources.Appliances, appliances),
    header: {
      Accept: 'application/json'
    }
  })
};

export const loadAppliances = () => {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    getResourceLinks()
      .then(res => {
        dispatch({
          type: ActionTypes.RESOURCE.LOAD_URL_SUCCESS,
          payload: res.body
        });

        return getAppliances(res.body)
          .then(res1 => {
            dispatch({
              type: ActionTypes.APPLIANCE.LOAD_SUCCESS,
              payload: res1.body
            });
          })
          .catch(err => {
            dispatch({
              type: ActionTypes.APPLIANCE.LOAD_ERROR,
              payload: err
            });
          });
      })
      .catch(err => {
        dispatch({
          type: ActionTypes.RESOURCE.LOAD_URL_ERROR,
          payload: err
        });
      });
  }
}
```

You also might want to take a look at [`redux-saga`](https://github.com/yelouafi/redux-saga)

Comment: I got your idea and tried it but I think it isn't the best way. I decide follow `redux-sage` but it seems a lot of things needed to learn. Thank you!